# C++ destructor called early

Tags: c++, memory-management, sdl

I have a class that manages a SDL_Surface for me, and I want to make it so that I don't have to worry about freeing the surface. I have this code so far:

```
//In Entity.h
class Entity
{
public:
    int x, y, width, height;

    Entity(std::string);
    ~Entity();
    void render();

private:
    SDL_Surface* texture;
};

//In Entity.cpp
Entity::~Entity()
{
    printf("Destroying an Entity");
    SDL_FreeSurface(texture);
}

//In main.cpp
Entity puppy("puppy.bmp");

void render() {
    clearScreen();

    puppy.render();
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    printf("started");
    init();

    bool done = false;
    while(!done) 
    {

        ...

        // Draw the screen
        printf("About to render");
        render();

        SDL_Flip(screen);

    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I get `Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000260
0x000000010002fd9b in SDL_DisplayFormat ()` Am I correct in assuming that the destructor is getting called early and it's trying to render a NULL texture? The code works fine if I don't have the destructor and just waste memory. I've also tried it with puppy being a local variable and passing it to render, but that doesn't help.

EDIT: The code runs for only a second, then crashes. It doesn't wait to exit the loop. Also, stepping through the program with gdb reveals the puppy to be drawn at least once for some reason. I've uploaded the full source here: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/2223161/sdlgame.zip

Comment: You don't seem to be doing any of the SDL initialization.

Comment: This doesn't look like your code, because that wouldn't even compile (or link, for that matter). In _your_ code, are you sure no copies of `Entity` are made?

Comment: @KerrekSB I removed some code to keep it from getting too long. The full source is at http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/2223161/sdlgame.zip

Comment: @willhelmtell It's my code, I cut some of it out to keep the post short. You can find the full code here: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/2223161/sdlgame.zip As for copies of entities, puppy is the only object of entity I have.

Comment: @Cole: I'm not really that keen on working through your code. It's up to you whether you want to provide a minimal, self-contained example here to get a helpful answer or if you want to have people guessing wildly. For now, I might just note that the root `Surface*` must not be cleaned up by you, because it's already being dealt with by SDL.

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry, I didn't mean to be unhelpful. Are you saying I shouldn't clean up the surface at all? Wouldn't that be garbage memory lying around?

Comment: @Cole: I really don't mind; I'm just saying that you probably get a better response if you make it as easy as possible for people to respond with as little effort on their part as possible. Anyway, check the SDL documentation; you're not supposed to touch the result of the initial surface creation function (I forget what it's called). Make a simple baby SDL program and valgrind it if you're not convinced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong end of the problem.  Your code ran for me after I moved the initialization of `puppy` into `main`.

By placing `puppy` as a global object, its constructor runs prior to `SDL_Init`.  The constructor calls `load_image`, which calls `SDL_DisplayFormat`.  The documentation warns:

> You have to call `SDL_Init` before using the `SDL_DisplayFormat` function. If you don't, your program will crash with an access violation.

http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_DisplayFormat

Of course, you should also ensure the destructor is called prior to `SDL_Quit()`, as is proper, though that's not what's causing your access violation at the moment.

Comment: Ah, I got it. I tried doing this before, but I just realized now that I probably have to make the parameter for render an Entity*. Now that I did that it worked. Is that what you did?

Comment: @Cole: I just made `puppy` into a pointer to an object declared within an inner scope of `main`.  That required the least effort on my part to get it working.  A better solution for you might be to declare a global `std::set<Entity*>` of all objects to be rendered, then iterate through each of them in `render`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a global variable:

```
Entity puppy("puppy.bmp");
```

it gets destroyed after your `main()` ends, so your `SDL_FreeSurface` gets called after `SDL_Quit()`. Is it valid? Check with documentation.

Comment: So the problem is probably that that the destructor is being called _too late_. Making `puppy` a variable wouldn't fix that either, because the destructor would be called at the end of main, still after `SDL_Quit()`. `int main() { { ... Entity puppy("puppy.bmp"); ... } SDL_Quit(); }` should work (note the extra curly braces used to create a scope.

Comment: As long as initialization of SDL happens before { Entity puppy ... }

Comment: That would be a good idea except that the program crashes after a few seconds of running, not when it exits the loop. I'll add this to the main post, but if I step through the program with gdb, the puppy gets drawn at least once, so I'm not sure what the issue is. @barnes53